# Why do the flags returned by fcntl(... F_GETFL) differ from the flags used to open the file descriptor via os.open?

Tags: python, unix, posix

I need to retrieve the flags of a open fd with fcnlt F_GETFL.

```
import os
import fcntl
fd = os.open('/tmp/test', os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR, 0777)
print  fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
print  os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR
```

i get:

32770 for the 1st print and 66 for the 2nd.
I was expecting to get the same flag output from the two prints.
Any ideas why there is a difference?
thx a lot
-jfas

Comment: FYI, the first result is equal to `os.O_BINARY | os.O_RDWR`.

Comment: i just realized the call to fcntl returns 32770(decimal) which is 100770 octal..that means fcntl returns the file type as well as the mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 2.7, and i don't have the same results:

```
>>> import os, fcntl
>>> fd = os.open('/tmp/test', os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR, 0777)
>>> print  fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
2
>>> print  os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR 
514
>>> print  fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
2
>>> print  os.O_CREAT
512
>>> print  os.O_RDWR
2
```

So only the flag O_CREAT is not here anymore. The status of the file after open is only O_RDWR.